# Spring Integration transaction strategy spanning file inbound adapter and queue channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a directory that is being read by an inbound file adapter which is piped into a priority channel that sorts the files by their name. I've created a transaction synchronization factory for moving the files after processing is done which works fine for the inbound adapter and all the transformations/aggregations that are happening in an additional file writer flow. As soon as I add the PriorityChannel, the transaction seems to be finished and it's not being passed to the transformation/aggregration logic.

Here is the inbound flow

```
return IntegrationFlows
                .from(fileReadingMessageSource,
                        c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                                             .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                                             .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
                                             .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
                                             .transactional(transactionManager())))
                .channel("alphabetically")
                .bridge(s -> s.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
                .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
                .get();
```

And the transaction synchronization strategy

```
@Bean
    TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
        syncProcessor.setBeanFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
        syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser.parseExpression(
                "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundProcessedDirectory.path " + " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
        syncProcessor.setAfterRollbackExpression(parser.parseExpression(
                "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundFailedDirectory.path " + " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
        return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
    }
```

Any idea how to span this transaction in combination with the priority queue channel? Or is there any other way that I could implement reading of files in an alphabetical order?

***EDIT1***

According to Gary, this should work (providing whole example as asked):

```
@Configuration
class FilePollingIntegrationFlow {

    @Autowired
    public File inboundReadDirectory;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.fixed.delay}") long period,
                                                  @Value("${inbound.file.poller.max.messages.per.poll}") int maxMessagesPerPoll, TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                                  MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(fileReadingMessageSource,
                        c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                                             .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                                             .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
                                             .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
                                             .transactional(transactionManager())))
                .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.thread.pool.size}") int poolSize) {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(poolSize);
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    PseudoTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new PseudoTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
        syncProcessor.setBeanFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
        syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser.parseExpression(
                "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundProcessedDirectory.path " + " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
        syncProcessor.setAfterRollbackExpression(parser.parseExpression(
                "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundFailedDirectory.path " + " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
        return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
    }

    @Bean
    public FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource(DirectoryScanner directoryScanner) {
        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setDirectory(this.inboundReadDirectory);
        source.setScanner(directoryScanner);
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectoryScanner directoryScanner(@Value("${inbound.filename.regex}") String regex) {
        DirectoryScanner scanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
        CompositeFileListFilter<File> filter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>(
                Arrays.asList(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(), new RegexPatternFileListFilter(regex), new AlphabeticalFileListFilter()));
        scanner.setFilter(filter);
        return scanner;
    }

    private class AlphabeticalFileListFilter implements FileListFilter<File> {
        @Override
        public List<File> filterFiles(File[] files) {
            List<File> list = Arrays.asList(files);
            list.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::getName));
            return list;
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
public class FilePollingConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="inboundReadDirectory")
    public File inboundReadDirectory(@Value("${inbound.read.path}") String path) {
        return makeDirectory(path);
    }

    @Bean(name="inboundProcessedDirectory")
    public File inboundProcessedDirectory(@Value("${inbound.processed.path}") String path) {
        return makeDirectory(path);
    }

    @Bean(name="inboundFailedDirectory")
    public File inboundFailedDirectory(@Value("${inbound.failed.path}") String path) {
        return makeDirectory(path);
    }

    @Bean(name="inboundOutDirectory")
    public File inboundOutDirectory(@Value("${inbound.out.path}") String path) {
        return makeDirectory(path);
    }

    private File makeDirectory(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        file.mkdirs();
        return file;
    }

}
```

By doing this and removing the PriorityChannel, it still seems that the transaction isn't working as I would thought. Using this flow, the file is not available in the Http outbound gateway. Any idea why?

```
@Component
public class MessageProcessingIntegrationFlow {

    public static final String OUTBOUND_FILENAME_GENERATOR = "outboundFilenameGenerator.handler";
    public static final String FILE_WRITING_MESSAGE_HANDLER = "fileWritingMessageHandler";
    @Autowired
    public File inboundOutDirectory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow writeToFile(@Value("${api.base.uri}") URI uri,
                                       @Value("${out.filename.dateFormat}") String dateFormat, @Value("${out.filename.suffix}") String filenameSuffix) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
                               .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID, m -> ((String) m
                                       .getHeaders()
                                       .get(FileHeaders.FILENAME)).substring(0, 17)))
                               .aggregate(a -> a.groupTimeout(2000)
                                                .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true))
                               .transform(m -> {
                                   MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                                   //noinspection unchecked
                                   ((List<File>) m).forEach(f -> body.add("documents", new FileSystemResource((File) f)));
                                   return body;
                               })
                               .handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri)
                                           .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                           .expectedResponseType(byte[].class))
                               .handle(Files.outboundGateway(inboundOutDirectory)
                                            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                                            .fileNameGenerator(
                                                    m -> m.getHeaders()
                                                          .get(FileHeaders.FILENAME) + "_" + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)
                                                                                                              .format(LocalDateTime
                                                                                                                      .now()) + filenameSuffix))
                               .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
                               .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gary Russel I came up with the following solution:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.fixed.delay}") long period,
                                                  @Value("${inbound.file.poller.max.messages.per.poll}") int maxMessagesPerPoll,
                                                  @Value("${inbound.file.poller.thread.pool.size}") int poolSize,
                                                  MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(fileReadingMessageSource,
                        c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                                             .taskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize))
                                             .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
                .channel("alphabetically")
                .bridge(s -> s.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
                .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
                .get();
    }
```

Advices with spec:

```
@Bean
    public Advice fileMoveAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setOnSuccessExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m -> renameMultiValueMapFiles(m, this.inboundProcessedDirectory)));
        advice.setOnFailureExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m -> renameMultiValueMapFiles(m, this.inboundFailedDirectory)));
        return advice;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler>> outboundSpec() {
        return new Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(GenericEndpointSpec<HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler> spec) {
                spec.advice(fileMoveAdvice(), retryAdvice());
            }
        };
    }

@SneakyThrows(IOException.class)
    private boolean renameMultiValueMapFiles(Message<?> m, File directory) {
        MultiValueMap<String, Resource> files = (MultiValueMap<String, Resource>) m.getPayload();
        List<File> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // no lambda to avoid ThrowsFunction type
        for (List<Resource> l : files.values()) {
            for (Resource v : l) {
                list.add(v.getFile());
            }
        }
        list.forEach(v -> v.renameTo(new File(directory.getPath(), v.getName())));
        return true;
    }
```

Added spec to handle:

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri)
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                            .expectedResponseType(byte[].class), this.advices.outboundSpec())
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot switch threads with Spring transactions; the transaction is bound to the thread.

You can use a custom `FileListFilter` in the message source instead and sort the files there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary for the tip. Could you please take a look at *EDIT1* and provide additional feedback?

Comment: You need top show the complete configuration as it stands now.

Comment: Please take a look again at the *EDIT1*. Hopefully that's what you've asked for. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Gary, not sure whether you were notified about my last EDIT1 so trying it again. Would appreciate your further guidance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a notification for some reason. I am not sure what you mean by "the file is not available in the Http outbound gateway.". Have you tried turning on DEBUG logging and following the messages through the flow? It looks to me like it should work OK.

Comment: No worries, I'm getting the following error in the http gateway:

`Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://xxx/rest/endpoint": file [C:\read\example.pdf] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: file [C:\read\example.pdf] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length`

Comment: Hi Gary, not sure whether the notification wasn't triggered again... Just checking again

Comment: Hmmm - no I didn't get a notification again; not sure what's going on :( It's generally better to edit the question with diagnostics like that. I'd like to see the full stack trace, including the thread name; turning on DEBUG logging should help as well - follow the message through the flow.

Comment: Trying again :) I've posted the stack trace as EDIT2 https://pastebin.com/8mJqydqa

Comment: Oh; you have a timeout on the aggregator `Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[12-345.678.M.0014]`. Of course that runs on another thread (from the scheduler).

Comment: Oh :) What would you suggest in this case? I don't think I can go around the aggregator timeout. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using a pseudo transaction to rename the files, you can use an [ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain) to the out bound gateway. See [the retry-and-more sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) for an example; it uses XML config but the concepts are the same. With the DSL, the advice goes on the endpoint spec.

Comment: Gary please take a look at my answer whether you would improve it somehow?